# Where is my Developer Certificate My .p12 file?

Tags: android, keystore

I'm looking for my "Developer Certificate file" so that I can publish my Android apps to Blackberry as well. Trouble is Blackberry is telling me that its a .p12 file and I dont have anything matching that anywhere in my files...not in my keystore, not in its parent folder, nowhere in my eclipse folders. Where am i missing to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're on Windows and haven't installed your Tizen SDK under a custom location, it should be in "C:\tizen-sdk-data\keystore\author" which is i hidden folder.